# Teradata sql assistant code completion aliases not working

Tags: teradata

Teradata SQL assistant version 16.20.

Code completion(The drop down suggestion list after i write dots) is not working for me when I use aliases, does anyone know why?

Comment: If you mean giving you a list of columns for a table in your query, it doesn't work for me with an alias or the actual table name, unless I specify <db>.<tablename>.

Comment: It actually works for me now. Not sure why it didn't work before. 

I had enabled Display suggestions in code editor both before and now. 

It feels kinda buggy but works with new code. Both with aliases and without db.

I get suggestions of dbs, tables, column, aliases, functions etc